# Delete records in different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, php, delete, xampp

I need to delete the records where UserIndex = 1 and ItemNumber = 5202 in all three tables, all in a single query. I am using SQL 2008 R2.

Table UserInfo1

| UserIndex | Itemnumber | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5202 | 99 |
| 1 | 1600 | 50 |
| 2 | 155 | 2 |
| 3 | 125 | 60 |

Table UserInfo2

| UserIndex | Itemnumber | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1265 | 50 |
| 4 | 1899 | 41 |
| 1 | 5202 | 99 |
| 3 | 125 | 60 |

Table UserInfo3

| UserIndex | Itemnumber | ItemCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5205 | 85 |
| 1 | 6666 | 41 |
| 3 | 4455 | 44 |
| 1 | 5202 | 50 |

I'm trying to use this query with two tables, but it doesn't work:

```
DELETE ItemInfo1, ItemInfo2 
FROM ItemInfo1 
LEFT JOIN ItemInfo2 
    ON ItemInfo1.UserIndex = ItemInfo2.UserIndex 
WHERE ItemInfo1.UserIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't ordinarily delete from more than one table in a single T-SQL `DELETE` statement.

It is possible to achieve the same effect using triggers or cascading foreign keys with an `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, but that's probably not what you need.

If you just want to submit a single batch of text and ensure all three deletion actions either succeed or fail as a unit, use a transaction:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        DELETE FROM dbo.UserInfo1
        WHERE
            UserIndex = 1 
            AND ItemNumber = 5202;

        DELETE FROM dbo.UserInfo2
        WHERE
            UserIndex = 1 
            AND ItemNumber = 5202;

        DELETE FROM dbo.UserInfo3
        WHERE
            UserIndex = 1 
            AND ItemNumber = 5202;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END CATCH;
```

More generally, it is a bad pattern to have such similar tables distinguished only by a suffix number. This suggests you really ought to have a single table instead with an extra column to distinguish the three sets.

A single statement `DELETE` would then be trivial.